# WS Security UsernameToken Not Populating in Generated XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I've had this issue that I cannot solve. I've researched heavily on Google and Stackoverflow, trying numerous variations but have yet to solve this.

I'm trying to utilize the WS-Security headers when passing over my xml request to an API i'm integrating with. My code looks like this:

```
        var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;

        var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("myendpointurl"));

        client = new MyWebService(binding, endPoint);
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

        // I use this to view the generated XML
        client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new myCustomInspector());
        client.Execute();
```

Right now the XML that is being generated with zero reference of the UsernameToken

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <s:Header>
     <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">...removed...</a:Action>
     <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:c304f179-8a25-40f4-a84e-dc5081be573e</a:MessageID>
     <a:ReplyTo>
       <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>.......
```

I'm completely at a loss of what to do next, i've tried so many variations but cannot for the life of me get the UsernameToken to generate

Comment: Why don't you use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view the message that gets sent over the wire, instead of using a custom message inspector?

Comment: Do they not produce the same xml? The issue I run into using fiddler is that i'm trying to send over HTTPS and i've yet to get it to work over HTTPS

Comment: I was able to get Fiddler working, the xml is the same, still missing the UsernameToken